# How to call a Cocoa App Method by AppleScript?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods, applescript

I made an app which has just a button which calls a method. I would like to implement the AppleScript possibility to call this method.

I read the Apple docs and made a *.sdef file in my project, but here are the problems:

I don't understand the object making for NSScriptCommand, I would like to just call an existing method in my project, how can I do it?

Here is my sdef file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">
<dictionary title="Live Control">
    <suite name="Live Control Suite" code="LivC" description="Live Control Scripts">
        <class name="session" code="sess" description="OTN Telnet Control">
            <cocoa class="NTLAppDelegate"/>
            <responds-to name="gotonext">
                <cocoa method="GoToNextFromScript:"/>
            </responds-to>
        </class>
    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

So I told that the class used is NTLAppDelegate and the method to call is "GoToNext:"

Here is my .h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NTLAppDelegate : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate> {

    NSInputStream * InputStream;
    NSOutputStream * OutputStream;
    unsigned char IACcommand[12];

}

- (IBAction)GoToNextButton:(id)sender;
- (id) GoToNextFromScript:(NSScriptCommand *)command;

@property (assign)

IBOutlet NSWindow * TheMainWindow;

@end
```

And my *.m file:

```
#import "NTLAppDelegate.h"

@implementation NTLAppDelegate
    
// GoToNext

- (id)GoToNextFromScript:(NSScriptCommand *)command {
    
    [ConnectLog setEditable:YES];
    [ConnectLog setString:@"APPLE SCRIPT TEST"];
    [ConnectLog setEditable:NO];
    
    return nil;
    
}

- (IBAction)SkipToNextButton:(id)sender {
    
    [ConnectLog setEditable:YES];
    [ConnectLog setString:@""];
    [ConnectLog setEditable:NO];
    
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)[HostField stringValue], [PortField intValue], &readStream, &writeStream);
    InputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    OutputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    
    [InputStream setDelegate:self];
    [OutputStream setDelegate:self];
    
...... rest is the code for the tcp stream control (input and output) not concerned .....

}

@synthesize TheMainWindow = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    
}

@end
```

So, nothing is working... When I read the apple script dictionary with the Apple Script editor,
I can read the sdef file but when I make an AppleScript like

tell application "Live Control
session gotonext
end tell

I get an error which say that the "gotonext" variable is not defined.

If someone can explain me how can I write this little thing, it would be great.
Note that I have, to be honest, a poor Obj-C / C++ knowledges,
but my app is working (just a cocoa app with one button, which open a tcp socket, send IAC command to telnet session and write a command). I just need the AppleScript control for this and all will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with how you have things set up. You'll really want to read the [Cocoa Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_intro/SAppsIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002164), and take a look at the old but still useful [Shadowlab SDEF Reference](https://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/SdefEditor/sdef-format.html).

So, first, a *class* in AppleScript implies a scriptable object-type within an application. When you define an AppleScript object using a 'class' block, the `<cocoa class="...">` is meant to point at a class you've written that holds the properties you specify. By default, all Apple Events are handled by the AppDelegate, so you never need to specify that it as a class (and it makes no sense to: the 'Application' is a separate object defined in the SDEF by the 'Application' class of the cocoa standard suite). In your case you'd probably want something like:

```
<class name="session" code="sess" description="OTN Telnet Control">
    <cocoa class="NTLTelnetSession"/>
```

Then you'd want to write a cocoa class called "NTLTelnetSession" with instance variables for all the attributes of a telnet session you are interested in. You'll also want to add an array in the AppDelegate to hold the instantiated object, tell the app delegate that it will handle the "NTLTelnetSession" key, and add object specifier methods so that scripting events can move up and down the object hierarchy: see the scripting guide for more intimation.

Second, you'll want to add a 'command' block to your SDEF so that CocoaScripting recognizes the command you want.  That would look something like:

```
<command name="go to nest" code="LivCGoTN" description="Move an object to a new location.">
</command>
```

note that the name should (conventionally) be written so that it could function as a verb phrase in a standard English sentence; composites like 'gotonext' are discouraged. See [Scripting Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2002/tn2106.html).

You have two options with commands: **object first** and **verb first** The distinction is that an *object first* command is something that your AppleScript object knows how to do for itself, while a *verb first* command is something that the application does to objects. In your case, that would mean these options:

- **Object first**: use a `responds-to` block as you did in your post, and write a mythos with the given name in your NTLTelnetSession class (not in the app delegate). This means that the telnet session object needs to know what 'next' refers to, and return the correct information
- **Verb first**: Either:

  1. Write a method with the appropriate signature in the app delegate, which will handle the command itself, or...
  2. Add a `<cocoa class="NTLGoToNextCommand"/>` element to the 'command' block, then write a class called "NTLGoToNextCommand" and implement the `performDefaultImplementation` method.

You can use both approaches, for instance if you have a generalized command that some objects know how to handle and other don't. Cocoa Scripting will always choose an object first command if one is available. But really, you should work your way through the Cocoa Scripting Guide: it's the poorly written gold standard for implementing scripting in your app.

Comment: The link above, to the "Cocoa Scripting Guide" appears to have originally been a mirror for the developer.apple.com doc "Scriptable Cocoa Applications". That link no longer has the file nor does developer.apple.com under either title. Too bad. My guess is that it was out of date (possibly describing Swift 3) and Apple declined to update it and simply removed it. Could that be why there seems to be a paucity of tutorial information for how to add AppleScript support to Swift/Cocoa?

Comment: @August: I fixed the link to the developer page version, if that helps. and don't think Swift 3; think OS 9. AppleScript is OOOOooooLLLD. And it's also always been kind of a hobbyist thing.  A few major companies (like Adobe) went in for it whole hog, but most developers either don't know about it at all or see it as too much (learning) overhead for the value. It really needs an update, but Apple seems fixated on iOSing everything these days.  Too sad...

Comment: Thanks Ted, I appreciate the updated link. I'm wanting AppleScript because it's well supported by Keyboard Maestro and I've been advised that some of the things I'm trying to do are much easier in AppleScript than in JSA. (That advice could be wrong.)